# How to iterate through multiple pdf's to extract first page from each file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I've written the below code to extract only the first page of the pdf and the code is working fine.
please refer the below code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = "C:\\Users\\abc\Data\first.pdf" 
pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
file_ext = path.replace('.pdf','')
pdfpage = [0]
PdfFileWriter = PdfFileWriter()

for page_num in pdfpage:
    PdfFileWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
with open('{0}_output.pdf'.format(file_ext),'wb') as a:
    PdfFileWriter.write(a)
    a.close()
```

The above code works fine and my question is how to extract the first page of multiple Pdf's?

For example I'm having pdf's like [first.pdf, second.pdf, third.pdf and so on] residing inside the same folder. Please pour some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your code into function and call it when you need it

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def function_for_one_pdf(name):    
    path = f"C:\\Users\\abc\Data\{name}.pdf" 
    pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
    file_ext = path.replace('.pdf','')
    pdfpage = [0]
    PdfFileWriter = PdfFileWriter()

    for page_num in pdfpage:
        PdfFileWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
    with open('{0}_output.pdf'.format(file_ext),'wb') as a:
        PdfFileWriter.write(a)
        a.close()


list_of_pdfs= ['first.pdf', 'second.pdf', 'third.pdf']         

for i in list_of_pdfs:
    function_for_one_pdf(i)
```

Comment: I have tried but throughs unbound error like " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'PdfFileWriter' referenced before assignment "

Comment: because there is no import of `PdfFileWriter`,